# How to access Clipping Rectangle postion of UIScrollView in NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, ngui

I am using NGUI v3.5.4r2 version. I am try to access Clipping Rectangle position in UIScrollView. I can get height and width of Clipping Rectangle but unable to access position of Clipping Rectangle of UIScrollView.

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks You.[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the position?

Comment: i want to get pink rectangle position in which grid item show in UIScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the localCorners variable of UIRect (of which UIPanel inherits) to get the Vector3 point of any of the corners.

```
UIPanel mPanel;
Vector3 bottom_Left = mPanel.localCorners[0];
Vector3 top_Left = mPanel.localCorners[1];
Vector3 top_Right = mPanel.localCorners[2];
Vector3 bottom_Right = mPanel.localCorners[3];
```